# How to convert collection of objects into arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, kotlin, collections

I can not do iteration, says that I can not convert my object to Collection, the conversion of that `Collection<Collection<Object>>`  to `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>`, in my case the object is `ExerciseModel()`

`val firstIterator : Collection<Collection<ExerciseModel>>` to my

`val arrayList : ArrayList<ArrayList<ExerciseModel>>`

Comment: What do you mean "I can not do iteration"?  I think you'll have to "do iteration" to solve this.

Comment: `val`? what java version?

Answer (score 0):

Just can convert a Collection to an ArrayList like this

```
  arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>(firstIterator);
```

Comment: its give me the error `ExerciseModel cannot be cast to java.util.Collection`

Answer (score 0):

you can use java-8 feature streams

`ArrayList<Foo> newList = firstIterator.stream().collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));`

you can check the sample stream here : https://www.baeldung.com/java-convert-collection-arraylist

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure I'm understanding your question but maybe this will work

```
val arrayList = firstIterator.map { it.toList() }
```

Comment: i need convert this `Collection<Collection<ExerciseModel>>` to this `ArrayList<ArrayList<ExerciseModel>>`

Comment: with this code line its give me the error : `ExerciseModel cannot be cast to java.util.Collection`

Comment: @MatheusSaviczki Well the code I posted should give you ```List<List<?>>```. It seems the problem lies with ```firstIterator```? Not sure how you're populating that